# Why I can't get img value from img by using onlick?

Tags: javascript

Quick question why I can't get img value from img by using onclick ?

or better yet can I use data-internalid to store some value and get it by on click ?

html

```
<div class="content_create"><img name="name" class='Dicon' id='Loader_images' src="src+" value="Code" onclick='getCode(this.value);'><p>typename</p></div>
```

JS

```
function getCode(_CODE){
    alert(_CODE);
    //getting null on here
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3fxzws1h/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value isn't allowed on HTML elements, except the `input` elements. However, does work and as suggested, you could use `getCode(this.attributes.value.value);` or `getCode(this.attributes.value.textContent);`.

But I would suggest you to change the `value` attribute to `data-value="Code"` to make your HTML valid and then using `getCode(this.dataset.value)`.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
getCode(this.value);
```

to

```
getCode(this.attributes.value.value);
```